# Error while installing AzureML extension on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

As said in title, I'm trying to add an AKS cluster to my Azure Machine Learning workspace as `Attached computes`.

In the wizard that ML studio shows while adding it

[image]

there's a link to a guide to [install AzureML extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/how-to-attach-kubernetes-anywhere).

Just 4 steps:

1. Prepare an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster or Arc Kubernetes
   cluster.
2. Deploy the AzureML extension.
3. Attach Kubernetes cluster to
   your Azure ML workspace.
4. Use the Kubernetes compute target from CLI
   v2, SDK v2, and the Studio UI.

My issue comes ad 2nd step.

As suggested I'm trying to [create a POC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-kubernetes-extension?tabs=deploy-extension-with-cli#azureml-extension-deployment---cli-examples-and-azure-portal) trough az cli

`az k8s-extension create --name <extension-name> --extension-type Microsoft.AzureML.Kubernetes --config enableTraining=True enableInference=True inferenceRouterServiceType=LoadBalancer allowInsecureConnections=True inferenceLoadBalancerHA=False --cluster-type managedClusters --cluster-name <your-AKS-cluster-name> --resource-group <your-RG-name> --scope cluster`

I'm already logged on right subscription (where I'm owner), ad using right cluster name and resource group. as extension-name I've used `test-ml-extension`, but I keep to get this error

`(ExtensionOperationFailed) The extension operation failed with the following error:  Request failed to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/<cluster-name>/extensionaddons/test-ml-extension?api-version=2021-03-01. Error code: Unauthorized. Reason: Unauthorized.{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant."}}. Code: ExtensionOperationFailed Message: The extension operation failed with the following error:  Request failed to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/<cluster-name>/extensionaddons/test-ml-extension?api-version=2021-03-01. Error code: Unauthorized. Reason: Unauthorized.{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant."}}.`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the Kubernetes cluster and launched the AML studio*

*In the AML I have created the workspace and created the compute with AKS cluster*

[image]

*Deployed the azureML extension using the below command*

```
az k8s-extension create --name Aml-extension --extension-type Microsoft.AzureML.Kubernetes --config enableTraining=True enableInference=True inferenceRouterServiceType=LoadBalancer allowInsecureConnections=True inferenceLoadBalancerHA=False --cluster-type managedClusters --cluster-name my-aks-cluster --resource-group Alldemorg --scope cluster
```

[image]

*I am able to see all the deployed clusters using below commands*

```
az k8s-extension show --name <extension_name> --cluster-type connectedClusters --cluster-name <connected_cluster_name> --resource-group <rg_name>
```

*After deploying the AzureML extension I am able to attach the Kubernetes cluster to azureML workspace.*

[image]

***NOTE:***

*ExtensionOperationFailed error may occur for the below of reasons,*

*1). Blocking of the the regions, for some AML clusters few of the regions are not allowed it will be blocked*

*2). Please check the version and upgrade to the latest version*

*3). While creating the extension please make sure cluster name it will be there in the AML workspace*

*4). The service principal for the cluster does not exist in the tenant in which we are trying to access*

*5). Each tenant in which we want to access must consent to the cluster, this will ensure the service principal exists in their tenant and that service principal has the access*

Comment: Thanks for reply! I followed the same steps, but it keeps failing. Maybe it's related to some subscription issues as pointed in your notes!

Answer (score 0):

I stumble into this error too. After a while of messing around, I finally fixed it by create 3 node pools on my AKS cluster (the default when create is only 2).